# js file - insert window.location into appended html

Tags: javascript, variables, var, window.location

I have a js file that is appending html. For one specific relative link, I need the link to be https. I'm assuming I would set a var, but I'm unsure how to insert it into the appended html within the js file.

```
$('#emailUpdates').append('<div class="head-popin ac-popin"><ul><li><a href="/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LLBLoginRedirectCmd?feat=ln&gUrl=ShowMAOAPLogin&lUrl=LLBOAPCouponLPAccessCheck&pgType=MA&storeId=1&catalogId=1&langId=-1">Coupon Lookup</a></li></ul></div>').css({
                    "padding-left": "78px"
                });
```

So the link above, I want the above to be something like `https:// +window.location.hostname +/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LLBLoginRedirectCmd?feat=ln&gUrl=ShowMAOAPLogin&lUrl=LLBOAPCouponLPAccessCheck&pgType=MA&storeId=1&catalogId=1&langId=-1`

But I'm unsure how to get that effect in this example.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var href = 'https://' + window.location.hostname + '/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/LLBLoginRedirectCmd?feat=ln&gUrl=ShowMAOAPLogin&lUrl=LLBOAPCouponLPAccessCheck&pgType=MA&storeId=1&catalogId=1&langId=-1';

var html = '<div class="head-popin ac-popin"><ul><li><a href="' + href + '">Coupon Lookup</a></li></ul></div>';

$('#emailUpdates').append(html).css({
    "padding-left": "78px"
});
```

Comment: thanks. I couldn't wrap my head around it, and didn't think to use two vars